# VisualStudio Code csharp debugger generating error

Tags: c#

I recently upgraded my version of VisualStudio Code to the latest release and am I getting an error when trying to debug csharp applications.  I am running in windows 10 (14393) and am using vs code 1.23.1.  I have an application that I created a few months ago using visual studio code and at the time it was working fine.  it is a MVC application that uses dotnetcore2.0.  When I try to run debugging I get a message "command 'csharp.coreclrAdapterExecutableCommand' not found.  I can execute the application by running "dotnet run" from the project folder.

I tried creating a new blank console application that just says "hello world" and again am able to run from "dotnet run" but when I try to debug I get the same message.  I am able to run the build task successfully.

I tried to reseaerch the method mentioned in the error but can find little to nothing about it.  I believe that omnisharp is the solution that the csharp debug runs in and I looked it up.  From their documentation it says that it needs .net framework 4.6 to work.  I verified that I have the sdk and runtime for each .net framework installed.

I am usually pretty good at figuring things like this out and this is my very first post on stack.  I am hoping that someone might know what the heck this is so that I can move forward.

It would be good to note that I have tried to reboot my machine several times and even uninstalled/reinstalled vs code.  An example of the launch.json file is below.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/helloworld/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/helloworld.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: In addition, it might be good to note that I tried rebooting several times as well as a complete uninstall and reinstall of VS Code.

Comment: Looks like this might be an OmniSharp and/or a VsCode bug. From this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1150) a workaround is to open the project and open a .cs file to get Vs Code to download the extension dependencies properly.

Comment: Could it be permissions issue on the folder or account you use? Debugging required admin access..

Comment: @bman7716 the link you provided helped guide me to the solution.  It was not the exact same scenario though it helped.  I will post the answer in another post to make it easier to be seen.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @bman7716 I was able to figure out what was going on.  The issue was the omnisharp extension was corrupted (or a related dependency).  I was able to resolve the issue by:

- Uninstalling the c# extension from VS Code
- Close VS Code
- remove all C:\Users{username}.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-{version}
- Open VS Code
- Install C# extension
- Open Project
- Go to Debug mode and start debug

This forced VS Code to re-install omnisharp and its dependencies and things worked just fine afterwards.